# Filtering a group of words from a String in Java using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have this string.

```
String longText  = "Associatepm: 4654-8199-9146";
```

and

```
String longText2 = "Associatepm: 465481999146";
```

I want to check if longText contains `4654-9199-9146` or `465491999146`
using regular expressions, and retrieve it.

```
String newLongText = 4654-8199-9146

System.out.println("The value of new long text" + newLongText); 
//prints 4654-8199-9146 or 465491999146
```

This is the code I've tried:

```
if(this.text.contains("associate 4444-4444-4444")){
  //print 4444-4444-4444
} else if(this.text.contains("associatepm 444444444444")){
  //print 444444444444
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you from writing your code? Do you get any errors, exceptions?

Comment: Will it always be a string of numbers/dashes after a colon?

Comment: why regular expressions?. This could be done using simple string operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        String text = "Associatepm: 4654-8199-9146";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        boolean b = m.find();
        if(b == true){
            text = text.replaceAll("\\D+","");
        }
        System.out.println(text);

    }
```

Special thanks to Ryan Reimer.

Comment: You actually should accept Ryan's answer, since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should match both of your scenarios.

[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}-?[0-9]{4}

https://regex101.com/r/gH2hN8/1

Comment: Nice one Ryan, so how do I use this to scan and extract the number from the longText.